# Learning Insertion Sort in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I have just started the MIT Introduction to Algorithms course through the material posted online. Along with the course I have also decided to learn/enhance my Ruby skills by coding the algorithms in it.

I am on the first algorithm given, which is Insertion sort, and I have the following code typed up but I am getting this error when I run it:

> insertionsort.rb:5:in `>': comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)

```
def  insertionsort(num)
for j in 2..num.length
    key = num[j]
    i = j - 1
    while i > 0 and num[i] > key
        num[i+1] = num[i]
        i = i - 1
    end
    num[i+1] = key
end 
puts num
end

numbers = [23,34,46,87,12,1,66]

insertionsort(numbers)
```

I'm sure it is a fairly basic problem but I just can't grasp what it is at the moment. Any  help or tips would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are overruning the bounds of your array.  The example you were given was assuming 1-indexed arrays, but arrays in ruby are 0-indexed.  The first line should be

```
for j in 1...num.length
```

Comment: Thanks, I just started to program this after I got done watching the lecture which use arrays starting at 1.

Answer (score 7):

The other answer is correct that you are going past the end of the values in the array because it is 0-based but there are other changes you need to make to make the algorithm work:

```
for j in 1..(num.length - 1)
```

and

```
while i >= 0 and num[i] > key
```

Comment: Yeah, once I realized my initial error I corrected the rest. Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest implementation is something like this:

```
def insertion_sort(arr)
  for i in (1...(arr.size))
    if arr[i-1] > arr[i]
      i.downto(1) do |el|
        if arr[el] < arr[el-1]
          arr[el-1], arr[el] = arr[el], arr[el-1]
        end
      end
    end
  end
  arr
end

arr = [5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3]

p insertion(arr)
```

Note: to improve the efficiency of algorithm you can use the Binary search for elements comparison.

[What Is Insertion Sort ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor complement to the other, excellent answers:

I think it is now generally accepted that 0-origin indexing has a number of practical and empirical advantages over 1-origin indexing. Experience suggests that it just "works better" and is less error-prone.

That's why a lot of programmers number things from zero, and astonish "normal" folks.

Comment: Eight years later, somebody finally voted this answer down. I bet you feel really proud of yourself, but if you could share the reason in a comment, we could all learn something!

Answer (score 0):

While this exercise is really cool, according to this excellent blog post you should probably avoid writing your own sort and rely on the built in Array::sort

http://philcrissman.com/2010/07/18/how-not-to-write-sorting-algorithms-in-ruby/

Answer (score 0):

```
class InsertionSort
  attr_accessor :arr

  def initialize(arr)
    self.arr = arr
  end

  def sort
    for i in (1...(arr.size))
      j = i
      while j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > arr[j]
        swap(j)
        j = j - 1
      end
    end
  end

  def swap(j)
    v1 = arr[j]
    v2 = arr[j - 1]
    arr[j - 1] = v1
    arr[j] = v2
  end
end

arr = [4, 92, 1, 39, 19]
isort = InsertionSort.new(arr)
isort.sort
puts isort.arr
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain how your code solves the OP's problem. It seems to be a pretty substantial rework of the OP's code and i am sure that not everyone here can understand the changes