# Having trouble with insertion sort algorithm in ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

So I'm trying to learn how to sort an array without using the .sort method, this is what I have so far, but the middle number is dropping out.

```
def  my_sort(num)
for j in 1...num.length
    key = num[j]
    i = j - 1
    while i > 0 and num[i] = key
            num[i+1] = num[i]
            i = i - 1
    end
    num[i+1] = key
end     

end
```

then I run the method

```
my_sort([3,1,2])
```

I get

```
=> 1...3
```

but I want

```
=> 1,2,3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38858611/1623261

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning the modified array, but instead the object fed into your `for` iterator.

What you're missing is simply leaving the array as the last thing in the method:

```
def my_sort(num)
  # ...

  num
end
```

As a note it's usually bad form to wreck the arguments you're given. A more polite function would return a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Actual implementation of insertion sort must look like:

```
def my_sort(arr)
  for j in 1...arr.length
    key = arr[j]
    i = j-1
    while i>=0 and arr[i] > key # You used arr[i] = key here instead
      arr[i+1] = arr[i]
      i = i-1
    end 
    arr[i+1] = key
  end 
  arr #return the array
end
```