# Sorting an Array in Ruby without using Sort method

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use the bubble sort method to sort an array of only three numbers. The code I'm using is below.

```
def my_sort(list)
  return list if list.size <= 1 

  swapped = false

  while !swapped
    swapped = false

    0.upto(list.size-2) do |i|
      if list[i] > list[i+1]
        list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]
        swapped = true
      end
    end

    list
  end

my_sort([3,1,2])
```

Here is the error message I keep getting:

```
Syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
```

I was just wondering which end shouldn't be included?

Comment: Indent the code properly and you'll see the missing `end` right away.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you sort without using the sort method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057381/how-do-you-sort-without-using-the-sort-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an `end` after `swapped = true`. It would be best to indent your code thoroughly and accurately to avoid this kind of problem:

```
def my_sort(list)
  return list if list.size <= 1 

  swapped = false
  while !swapped
    swapped = false
    0.upto(list.size-2) do |i|
      if list[i] > list[i+1]
        list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]
        swapped = true
      end
    end
  end

  list
end
```

Comment: this did not work. list  = [14,11,36,42,12,10] is returning  sorted array as [11, 14, 36, 12, 10, 42] which is wrong.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work; it returned the same array unsorted.

Comment: this is the OPs code, but correctly indented and with the syntax error fixed

Answer (score 3):

You're missing an `end`

```
  if list[i] > list[i+1]
    list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]
    swapped = true
  end # <--------------------------------------------------------
```

**Edit:**
As the other answer mentions, indent your code to make these errors more visible.

Answer (score 2):

**This looks a better and quicker one**.

```
arr = [1,5,7,2,3,50,78,34, 1, 15, 89, 8]

def sort_array(arr)
  arr.size.times do
    arr.map.with_index do |num, index|
      next if index.eql?(arr.size - 1)
      arr[index], arr[index+1] = arr[index+1], arr[index] if num > arr[index+1]
    end
  end
end
```

Call the above method as `print sort_array(arr)` to get expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for that specific array. Because your loop is looking if the next element is higher, then swipe. But what about more elements in the array? This is recursive solution for all cases.

```
def my_sort(list, new_array = nil)

  return new_array if list.size <= 0
  if new_array == nil
    new_array = []
  end
  min = list.min
  new_array << min
  list.delete(min)

  my_sort(list, new_array)

end

puts my_sort([3, 1, 2, 20, 11, 14, 3, 6, 8, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

**What worked for me, is below.**

```
def my_sort(list)   
  n = list.length   
  loop do
    swapped = false
    (n-1).times do |i|
      if list[i] > list[i+1]
        list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]
        swapped = true
      end
    end
    break if not swapped  
  end   
  list 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort(arr)
    arr_len = arr.length - 1
    swap = true
    while swap
        swap = false
        arr_len.times do |i|
         if arr[i] > arr[i+1]
           arr[i],arr[i + 1] = arr[i + 1],arr[i]
           swap = true
         end
        end
     end
     p arr

end
```

Comment: Please add a bit explanation why this code should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1,2,8,4,5,3,1,0,6]

0.upto(arr.size - 1) do |i|
  (i+1).upto(arr.size - 1) do |j|
    if arr[i] > arr[j]
      arr[j],arr[i] = arr[i],arr[j]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#Using bubble sort algorithm in ruby

a = [1,5,7,2,3,50,78,34,89]

a.size.times.each do |t|
 i=0
 a.each do |b|
   if b > a[i+1]
     a[i],a[i+1] = a[i+1],a[i]
   end
   i+=1 if i < a.size-2
 end
end
print a
#output: [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 34, 50, 78, 89]
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue. Please update your answer to explain how this improves on the other accepted and upvoted answers this question already has. Also, this question is 5 years old, your efforts would be more appreciated by users who have recent unanswered questions. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).