# Why does the code incorrectly sort the two arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, for-loop

***Here is an update in my attempt at solving the problem***
Why does it sort the array in reverse? Logic makes sense to me.

```
def combine_array(arr1,arr2)
arr3 = []
arr1.each do |x|
    arr3.push(x)
end

arr2.each do |x|
    arr3.push(x)
end

arr3.each_index do |i|
    arr3.each_index do |j|
      if arr3[i] > arr3[j]
        hold = arr3[i]
        hold2 = arr3[j]
        arr3[i] = hold2
        arr3[j] = hold
      end
end
end
return arr3
```

end

combine_array([1,5,3],[6,2,4])

[Click link to see the code and the array in reverse order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCULt.png)

Comment: I assume there's a reason you don't want to just do `(arr1 + arr2).sort`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it. Your assumption is correct.

Comment: Should we help you with the original code or the updated one? I'd say pick one and stick with it. If you have a solution, you may post it as an answer. Changing the question however is confusing.

Comment: @Stefan Sorry for the confusion. I condensed the question to me less confusing

Comment: @TarekulIslam are you trying to implement a specific sort algorithm?

Comment: @Stefan No. I am trying to understand the error in my code or logic.

Answer (score 1):

1. You iterated over `arr3[i+1..-1].each_index do |j|`, and then referred fo `arr3[j]`, but that is a frontal portion of `arr3`, which you probably haven't intended. `j` is an index within `arr3[i+1..-1]`, not `arr3`.
2. You only go through `arr3` once, and not all array can be sorted by just one pass in your algorithm.

Comment: I disagree I go through arr3 multiple of times. If you notice their is for loop within a for loop. For each index in arr3 I go through rest of arr3.
For Example: in the array [1,5,3,6,2,4]
I compare the value in index 0 which is 1 to  1,5,3,6,2,4 
than I compare value in index 1 to 5,3,6,2,4. Since 5 is greater than 3 i switch the numbers. Than i continue comparing the value in index 1 to 6,2,4 until the value in that index is fully sorted.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

```
def combine_array(arr1,arr2)
arr3 = []
arr1.each do |x|
    arr3.push(x)
end

arr2.each do |x|
    arr3.push(x)
end

arr3.each_index do |i|
    j = i+1
    until j == arr3.length  do
        if arr3[i] > arr3[j]
            hold = arr3[i]
            hold2 = arr3[j]
            arr3[i] = hold2
            arr3[j] = hold
        end
        j+=1
    end
end
return arr3
```

end

combine_array([1,5,3],[6,2,4])

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use the .sort method, here is another approach which might be of interest:
[Sorting an Array in Ruby without using Sort method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106981/sorting-an-array-in-ruby-without-using-sort-method)